# How do I lock the footer height for multiple pages with the same css sheet

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

My index sheet footer section is an appropriate height but whenever I link the second clickable page to the style sheet or the second page. The footer section is elongated, how can I make the footer the same height for every page after.

I would like the footer to stay the same on multiple pages that are created from the menu bar like the footer on most websites. Is there a way to properly do this?
HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>All Products - Only Leaf | Store</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
</head>
<body>

</----Page information---->

<!-----------------------------footer------------------------------------->
        <div class="footer">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="footer-col-1">
                        <h3>Follow Us on our Social Media Page.</h3>
                        <p>Follow us to stay up to date on products and giveaways</p>
                    </div>
                
                    <div class="footer-col-2">
                        <img src="Images/instagram.jpg">
                        <p>Follow us on Instagram to see the Latest with Only Leaf.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="footer-col-3">
                        <h3>Useful Links</h3>
                            <ul>
                                    <li>Coupons</li>
                                    <li>Blog with Station 33</li>
                                    <li>Return Policy</li>
                                    <li>Join Affiliates</li>
                            </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="footer-col-4">
                        <h3>Useful Links</h3>
                            <ul>
                                    <li>Twitter</li>
                                    <li>Facebook</li>
                                    <li>Instagram</li>
                                    <li>Station 33</li>
                            </ul>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <p class="copyright">Copyright 2021 - theElement</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html body{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
    
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #555;
}
p{
    color: #555;
}
.header{
    background: radial-gradient(#fff,#ffd6d6);
}
.collapse ul {
    background-color: #ff523b; 
    
}

.container{
    max-width: 1300px;
    margin: auto;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    
}
.navbar{
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    min-height: 22px;
    margin-right: 45px;
}
.navbar-custom{
    background-color: #ff523b;
}
.navbar-custom .nav-link:hover{
    color: black;
}
.navbar.navbar-inverse {
    border: none;
  }

.navbar .navbar-custom .navbar-brand img {
    height: 85px;
    padding-left: 39%;
    
  }
  .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: #ff523b;
}
.custom-toggler .navbar-toggler{
    border-color: #000;
}
  .navbar ul.navbar-nav li.nav-item a.nav-link {
    color: #fff;
    padding-right: 25px;
    margin-right: 25px;
  }

#navbarMenu{
    align-items: flex-end;
    padding-right: 5%;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    nav.navbar .navbar ul.navbar-nav li.nav-item a.nav-link {
      background-color: lightgray;
      
    }
  }



/*----.
.navbarMenu{
    padding: 75px;
}
nav{
    flex: 1;
    text-align: right;
}
nav ul{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
}
nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
}---*/
.menu-icon{
    display: none;
    width: 28px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.row{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
/*---------*/
    
}
.header .row{
    margin-top: 70px;
}
.col-2{
    flex-basis: 50%;
    min-width: 300px;
}

.col-2 img{
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 50px 0;
}
.col-2 h1{
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 60px;
    margin: 25px 0;
}
.btn{
    display: inline-block;
    background: #ff523b;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 8px 30px;
    margin: 30px 0;
    border-radius: 30px;
    transition: background 0.5s;
}
.btn:hover{
    background: #563434;
}

/*-----------------------------*/
.categories{
    margin: 70px 0;
}

.small-container{
    max-width: 1080px;
    margin: auto;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
}

.col-3{
    flex-basis: 30%;
    min-width: 250px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.col-3 img{
    width: 100%;
}
/*----------------Featured Product----------------------*/
.title{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto 80px;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 60px;
    color: #555;
}
.title::after{
    content: '';
    background: #ff523b;
    width: 80px;
    height: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.col-4{
    flex-basis: 25%;
    padding: 10px;
    min-width: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
}
.col-4 img{
    width: 100%;
}
h4{
    color: #555;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.col-4 p{
    font-size: 14px;
}
.rating .fa{
    color:  #ff523b;
}
.col-4:hover{
    transform: translateY(-5px);
}

/*----------------------------offer------------------------------*/
.offer{
    background: radial-gradient(#fff, #ffd6d6);
    margin-top: 80px;
    padding: 30px 0;
}
.col-2 .offer-img{
    border-radius: 15% 30% 30% 5%;
    padding: 50px;
}
small{
    color: #555;
}


/*----------------------------Testimonial------------------------------*/
.testimonial{
    padding-top: 100px;
}
.testimonial .col-3{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 40px 20px 40px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
}
.testimonial .col-3 img{
    width: 50px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.fa.fa-quote-left{
    font-size: 34px;
    color: #ff523b;
}
.col-3 p{
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 12px 0;
    color: #777; 
}
.testimonial .col-3 h3{
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #555;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.testimonial .col-3:hover{
    transform: translateY(-10px);
}

/*----------------------------Brands------------------------------*/
.brands{
    margin: 100px auto;
}
.col-5{
    width: 160px;
}
.col-5 img{
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}
.col-5 img:hover{
    filter: grayscale(0);
}
 /*----------------------------Footer------------------------------*/
 #footer{
     position: relative;
     height: 10%;
 }
 .footer{
     background: #000;
     color: #8a8a8a;
     font-size: 14px;
     padding: 60px 0 20px;
 }
.footer p{
    color: #8a8a8a;
}
.footer h3{
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.footer-col-1, .footer-col-2, .footer-col-3, .footer-col-4{
    min-width: 250px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.footer-col-1{
    flex-basis: 30%;
}
.footer-col-2{
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center;
}
.footer-col-2 img{
    width: 180px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.footer-col-3, .footer-col-4{
    flex-basis: 12%;
    text-align: center;
}
.footer ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #000;
}
.footer hr{
    border: none;
    background: #b5b5b5;
    height: 1px;
    margin: 20px 0;
}
.copyright{
    text-align: center;
}

/*--------------media query for menu---------------*/

@media screen and (min-width: 800px){
    
} 

/*---------------All Products----------------*/
.row-2{
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 100px auto 50px;
}
select{
    border: 1px solid #ff523b;
    padding: 5px;
}
select:focus{
    outline: none;
}
.page-btn{
    margin: 0 auto 80px;
}
.page-btn span{
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ff523b;
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.page-btn span:hover{
    background: #ff523b;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: You used the wrong indexer (not sure if correct name for it) in your css. You have one #footer, but you use that ID nowhere shouldn't that be .footer?

Comment: This feels like it should be reversed in order to me `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">`

Comment: why are you putting bootstrap CSS in twice?`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" `